# How many ways to make change for a dollar using at most as many pennies as nickels?

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to compute how many ways there are to make change for a dollar when the amounts of each coin denomination I use depend on each other. My idea is to find the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in $\sum_{j=0}^{100}p^jx^j\sum_{k=0}^{20}n^kx^{5k}$, which will be a polynomial in $p,n$, and then going through term by term and saying that terms in which the degree of $p$ is less than or equal to the degree of $n$ contribute 1 to my total count, and everything else contributes 0.

I am actually trying to figure out what the precise number is, and I feel confident that this method works, but I'm finding it impossible to execute code for it - this method absolutely eats memory. Is there a nicer way to express the generating function so that it's easier to code?

Comment: Are you familiar with the general problem of finding the number of ways to make change with no restrictions? If so, combine the penny and the nickel into a six cent piece, solve the problem and then convert instances of the six cent piece into a nickel and a penny.

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to find solutions to
$$p+5n=100$$
where $p\leq n$. This means that $n=p+q$ where $q$ is some nonnegative integer. So this is equivalent to finding the number of nonnegative integer solutions to
$$p+5(p+q)=100$$
$$6p+5q=100$$
There are only solutions if $p=0,5,10,15$ for a total of $\boxed{4}$ solutions.